# Application of Vieta's formula

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Could anyone advise me on how to use Vieta's formula to solve the following problem: If $a+b+c= 12, a^2+b^2+c^2=50, a^3+b^3+c^3=168,$ find $a,b,c.$

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

By [Newton's identities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_identities):
$$ a+b+c = 12,\qquad ab+ac+bc = 47, \qquad abc = 44$$
hence $a,b,c$ are the roots of the polynomial:
$$p(x)= x^3-12x^2+47x-44$$
that has just one real root, close to $1.348$.